# Buildroot error : failed to generate boot.vfat

Tags: local, buildroot

I am trying to compile some personal python libraries to Buildroot for an embedded device. Here is one of my makefiles :

```
LXML_VERSION = 4.6.3
LXML_SITE = /home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/package/CNES/lxml/lxml
LXML_SITE_METHOD = local

LXML_SETUP_TYPE = setuptools

LXML_DEPENDENCIES = libxml2 libxslt zlib
HOST_LXML_DEPENDENCIES = host-libxml2 host-libxslt host-zlib

LXML_BUILD_OPTS = \
    --xslt-config=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/bin/xslt-config \
    --xml2-config=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/bin/xml2-config
HOST_LXML_BUILD_OPTS = \
    --xslt-config=$(HOST_DIR)/bin/xslt-config \
    --xml2-config=$(HOST_DIR)/bin/xml2-config

$(eval $(python-package))
$(eval $(host-python-package))
```

As you can see, the makefile is almost exactly the default make file for python-lxml. It is also the case for my other libraries. I only changed the source and the method to have buildroot go into my local library.

Here's what I get as an error :

```
>>>   Executing post-image script board/zynq/post-image.sh
[...]
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'u-boot.img' as 'u-boot.img' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/images/u-boot.img' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'devicetree.dtb' as 'devicetree.dtb' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/images/devicetree.dtb' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'uImage' as 'uImage' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/images/uImage' '::'" (stderr):
Disk full
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "rm -f "/home/mso-aerosat/Desktop/cecilia_workspace/Buildroot/buildroot-2021.02.7/output/images/boot.vfat"" (stderr):
ERROR: vfat(boot.vfat): failed to generate boot.vfat
make[1]: *** [Makefile:836: target-post-image] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:84: _all] Error 2
```

And finally here is the post-image.sh script :

```
#!/bin/sh

# By default U-Boot loads DTB from a file named "devicetree.dtb", so
# let's use a symlink with that name that points to the *first*
# devicetree listed in the config.

FIRST_DT=$(sed -n \
           's/^BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_INTREE_DTS_NAME="\([a-z0-9\-]*\).*"$/\1/p' \
           ${BR2_CONFIG})

[ -z "${FIRST_DT}" ] || ln -fs ${FIRST_DT}.dtb ${BINARIES_DIR}/devicetree.dtb

support/scripts/genimage.sh -c board/zynq/genimage.cfg
```

Here is the link to the source code from github, in case you'd need to see other scripts : https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/master/board/zynq/post-image.sh

How can I solve the problem ? If I change the menuconfig to not add the libraries, it works without an error. But as soon as I add those, it won't. Any advice please ?

Thank you !

Comment: The problem occurs during the execution of **post-image.sh**, but you neglect to show that script in your post.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it was relevant ! I edited the question to add the script !

Answer (score 0):

So I did `make clean` and then `make` again and the error was removed but I still don't have my customized libraries in ouput/target. They are correctly added in output/built though. I don't know why Buildroot doesn't treat them until the end of the process...